Podman Quadlet replicate using template files
I'm experimenting with Podman Quadlets and trying to scale an app using a Quadlet template. However, I'm running into an issue with the port format when using a dynamic variable %i in the PublishPort field.
After running a dry run with podman-system-generator --user --dryrun, I get the following error:
quadlet-generator[24155]: Loading source unit file /home/filip/.config/containers/systemd/node-app@.container
quadlet-generator[24155]: converting "node-app@.container": invalid port format '300%i'

Quadlet file node-app@.container:
[Service]
Restart=always

[Container]
ContainerName=node-app-%i
Image=localhost/node-app:latest
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
PublishPort=300%i:3000

I plan to scale the instances like this:
systemctl --user enable --now node-app@1
systemctl --user enable --now node-app@2
systemctl --user enable --now node-app@3

Containerfile:
FROM node:22-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]

Simple app example server.js:
const http = require("node:http")

const hostname = "0.0.0.0";
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    res.end("Hello World\n");
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

Is there a correct way to dynamically assign ports in Quadlet using something like $i in the PublishPort field, or is there another approach I should take to achieve this?

Do you mean to be using %i instead of $i in the port expression?

@larsks my bad, it's a typo with $i; the output for examples was used with %i

As alternative you could also use socket activation. Then you would use %i in the ListenStream= configuration. Man page: socket unit A google search gave me: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket-activation

@ErikSjölund podman v5.3 now supports variable in PublishPort

Podman v5.3
Since version v5.3.0-rc2 implemented the PublishPort key in Quadlet .container and .pod files can now accept variables in its value.
I've updated quadlets and app
[Service]
Restart=always

[Container]
ContainerName=node-app-%i
Image=localhost/node-app:latest
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
Environment=PORT=300%i
PublishPort=300%i:300%i

const http = require("node:http")

const hostname = "0.0.0.0";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    res.end("Hello World\n");
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

Now I can run
$ systemctl --user start node-app@1
$ systemctl --user start node-app@2
$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                      COMMAND               CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                   NAMES
368c4f8e1a6c  localhost/node-app:latest  node --no-warning...  2 minutes ago  Up 2 minutes  0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp  node-app-1
a8c69395e4de  localhost/node-app:latest  node --no-warning...  1 second ago   Up 2 seconds  0.0.0.0:3002->3002/tcp  node-app-2

$ curl localhost:3001
Hello World
$ curl localhost:3002
Hello World


Systemd uses % as variable substitution, I assume you mean %i.
The quadlet generator doesn't accept anything other than numbers on PublishPort but it works fine on Environment etc.
This is because quadlet validates that the port is in the correct range. Systemd will not have that problem when it reads template files but it means you cannot dynamically generate containers from .container files (just from templated service files).
You can use the quadlet generator on your first .container-file and then manually convert it so a template unit by renaming it to mycontainer@.service and placing the instance name (%i) on the correct places.
For a templated nginx container the ExecStart would be changed to:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run --name=mycontainer-%i --cidfile=%t/%N.cid --replace --rm --cgroups=split --sdnotify=container -d --publish 80%i:80 docker.io/nginx:1.27-alpine-slim

And started with:
 systemctl start mycontainer@81
 systemctl start mycontainer@82
 systemctl start mycontainer@83

podman ps:
c2770183fcb8  docker.io/library/nginx:1.27-alpine-slim  nginx -g daemon o...  9 seconds ago  Up 9 seconds         0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp                      mycontainer-81
5a63dbebdf77  docker.io/library/nginx:1.27-alpine-slim  nginx -g daemon o...  3 seconds ago  Up 3 seconds         0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp                      mycontainer-82
f17ca6f0c967  docker.io/library/nginx:1.27-alpine-slim  nginx -g daemon o...  3 seconds ago  Up 3 seconds         0.0.0.0:8083->80/tcp                      mycontainer-83

EDIT:
For your node-app you would:

place a normal node-app.container in  ~/.config/containers/systemd/node-app.container (with port 3001)
run /usr/libexec/podman/quadlet -dryrun -user.
Save the systemd-unitfile is printed out
Place that file in ~/.config/systemd/user/node-app@.service
Replace the port 3001 with 300%i and add -i% to the name of the service and the container.
Remove the .container-file
run systemctl --user daemon-reload
run systemctl --user enable --now node-app@1
check with podman ps to ensure node-app-1 started


Could you clarify what you mean by "manually convert it to a template unit by renaming it to mycontainer@.service and placing the instance name (%i) in the appropriate locations"?

Since quadlet validates PublishPort it can't be used with template variables. I updated my answer on how to change a correctly generated unit to a template unit that can start many containers.

I'm still confused by your approach. The whole point of a template is that you don't need to edit it to start multiple instances. You also suggested using 300%i, which I tried, but I mentioned that it didn't work.

You tried 300%i in the .container-file which quadlet transforms into a .service-file.
The quadlet systemd generator doesn't handle templated values so you put those values in afterwards, in the .service-file. That template can start multiple containers without edit.
